# What's wrong with my po2php syntax

Tags: php, python, pootle, translate-toolkit

What's wrong with my syntax?

```
po2php -t /var/www/pootle/fortemplating/language.php -i /var/www/pootle/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pootle/translations/myproject/zh_TW/lang.po -o /var/www/pootle/translated2php/zh_TW/language.php
```

the created language.php doesn't create the translated file but only english texts

Answer (score 0):

It was actually a problem with the translate kit. My template uses

```
return array (
```

which is not supported and was just recently discovered. Try following this thread for update https://github.com/translate/translate/issues/3283